# PHP variable concatenation and text file line breaks

Tags: php, line-breaks

My php variables are like

```
$boothsizetopges = "CHILDREN'S CLUB MARCH 2013
EHIBITING COLLECTION NAME: $company
BOOTH SIZE: $booth_size
"; 

$companyinfo = "
CONTACT INFORMATION
EXHIBITING COLLECTION NAME: $company
BOOTH NUMBER: $booth
CONTACT: $contact
BOOTH SIZE: $booth_size
CONTACT CELL: $contact_cell
CONTACT EMAIL: $email
STREET ADDRESS: $street
CITY, STATE, ZIP: $city ";

$message = $boothsizetopges . $companyinfo ;
```

and my code for writing $message to a .txt file is

```
$myFile = "exfiles/".str_replace(" ","-",$_POST['companyname'])."_".time().".txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $message;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Here my problem is in .txt file output is printing in a single line without line breaks..
But in mails the data is coming fine in each line.

Need help...

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks aren't present? How do you open to view the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening the text file in Windows?  If so you may be encoding unix-style line breaks (\n) when you need to use Window's style (\r\n).  As a simple test add to the end of your first code block:

```
$message = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $message);
```

Generally though, you just want to stick with unix-style (IMHO)